# Django form validation fails when dynamically creating form by overwriting __init__

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm writing a prediction app in Django. At a basic level it pulls matches from an API, populates the database, and finally allows users to make predictions on matches that have not yet been played. As I don't know how many matches will be in a tournament before the fact, I wanted to create a form that dynamically adds as many fields as is required.

I currently have a "working" version but it would create issues further down the line. Here's the working version: *(Fair warning, this is me testing, so excuse the naming conventions)*

**views.py**

```
def ftest(request, contest_id):
    matches_list = Matches.objects.filter(
        matches_contest_pk__id = contest_id
    ).filter(
        matches_complete = False
    ).order_by(
        '-matches_start_time'
    )

    matches = [
        f'{match.matches_team_1} vs. {match.matches_team_2}'
        for match in matches_list
    ]

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TestForm(form_fields = matches, data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = TestForm(form_fields = matches)

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'predictions/test.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Matches

class TestForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form_fields = kwargs.pop('form_fields', None)
        super(TestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in form_fields:
            self.fields[field] = forms.CharField(label = f'{field}', max_length = 100)
```

As I said, this works but I would, ideally, like to have the id of each field set to the actual id from the database. My solution to this was to alter the view to send a list of dicts through `form_fields` and updating the form to work with that instead. So this is what that looks like:

**views.py**

```
def ftest(request, contest_id):
    matches_list = Matches.objects.filter(
        matches_contest_pk__id = contest_id
    ).filter(
        matches_complete = False
    ).order_by(
        '-matches_start_time'
    )

    matches = [
        { 'label': f'{match.matches_team_1} vs. {match.matches_team_2}', 'id': match.id, }
        for match in matches_list
    ]

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TestForm(form_fields = matches, data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = TestForm(form_fields = matches)

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'predictions/test.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Matches

class TestForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form_fields = kwargs.pop('form_fields', None)
        super(TestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in form_fields:
            self.fields[field['id']] = forms.CharField(label = field['label'], max_length = 100)
```

However with this change, the form doesn't pass validation. It just throws an `This field is required.` error for every field. Ideally I'd the user to be returned to the same page and have the fields be filled in with their predictions. Any advice on how to fix this? Am I approaching the problem from the wrong angle or am I misunderstanding how forms work in Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The problem lied with what I was sending to the form creation method. When I created the dict, this is how it was done:

```
    matches = [
        { 'label': f'{match.matches_team_1} vs. {match.matches_team_2}', 'id': match.id, }
        for match in matches_list
    ]
```

Turns out that the the issue was with the 'id' key. I assigned it an integer and it needs to be a string in the form creation. So the solution looks like:

```
    matches = [
        { 'label': f'{match.matches_team_1} vs. {match.matches_team_2}', 'id': str(match.id), }
        for match in matches_list
    ]
```